# Return multiple numbers in one integer

Tags: java, string, char

This is my simple code that converts chars into numbers (because then I will have to do bubble-sort.) I want to return an integer that is the combination of the Ascii of my chars.
For example if I have a string like "b78" my method "ascii" should do something like this:

`'b' = 98, '7' = 55, '8'=  56`

But I want to return it as one integer: `985556`. I would like to return only a integer, *not an array*, int[]. What do I have to do to achieve this?

```
public class Example{
    public static int ascii(String s){ 
        for(int i=0 ; i < s.length() ; i++){
            char c = s.charAt(i);
            int j= (int)c;
        }
        // I don,t know what I have to return
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String[] str = {"b78","c&3","a00","a01","zz9"};
        String q = str[0];

        int c = ascii(q);
        System.out.print(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not easier to return a list or other data structure?

Comment: Convert each number into a `String` and concatenate them all together. Then when you're done, parse that string back into an `int` and return it.

Comment: *Why* would you want to do that? At *least* return an array!

Comment: @chrylis    Because then I want to compare the other String of my array , I have to reorder in descending order my array of String ( So I supposed that i need an integer to do this )

Comment: You really DON'T want to do this.  If you do it as you describe, they'll get sorted out of order.  Just compare them as Strings.

Comment: @DavidWallace By using equals() or compareTo() ? Because my teacher told me that I have to do this converting chars into integer, then reorder . Because I can't reorder an aray of String :(

Comment: Why can't you reorder an array of `String`?  Has your teacher forbidden this?

Comment: @DavidWallace   No , because Im not able

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the example you gave, I think you wanted something like

```
public static int ascii(String s) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        sb.append(Integer.toString(c));
    }
    return Integer.parseInt(sb.toString());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] str = { "b78", "c&3", "a00", "a01", "zz9" };
    for (String q : str) {
        int c = ascii(q);
        System.out.printf("%s %d%n", q, c);
    }
}
```

Output is

```
b78 985556
c&3 993851
a00 974848
a01 974849
zz9 12212257
```

Comment: @Francesco Do you want `az9` to come after `za9`?

Comment: @DavidWallace I just want to reorder the array of string , in descendig order, doesn't matter the method . I supposed that convert string into numbers was a good idea so I asked for this .

Comment: Yes, but if you use _this_ method,  they _won't_ come out in descending order.

Comment: @DavidWallace Sorry I'm new in Java. Yeah it's true, but if I convert String in numbers and then I will write a method that reorder these numbers why It won't works? In that situation zz9 is the biggest so is the first and then a00 is the smallest so it is the last ones.

Comment: But `az9` will give you `9712257` and `za9` will give you `1229757`, which is less.  So those two will end up being out of order.  You really need to re-think this.  As I said in the comments under the question, you truly do NOT want to convert your Strings to integers.  Just compare them as Strings.  You said you couldn't, but you didn't say why.  @Francesco

Comment: Damn it's true, really what a fail :( by the way, because I'm not able to compare String and than reorder that. I never used this method,  I will Google this @DavidWallace

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you try this, but I think you can use + operator of string concatenation. convert each character into its ASCII and convert this integer into string, with using Integer.toString(). then concatenate them with + operator, and convert the result again with Integer.parseInt(String str) method again. I guess then you can get the result that you want.